# General solution for differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation that I try to find a general solution :

$$\frac{dx\left(t\right)}{dt}=x\left(t\right)\left(1-x\left(t\right)\right)-ay\left(t\right)$$

Since there is the variable $x^2$, I tried to transform the variable in order to have a simpler one but it did not work. How can I solve this equation of where should I look in order to have an intuition to solve it ?

Comment: This is a special case of the [Riccati equation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation).

Comment: This DE is called the logistic equation with harvest and there is no explicit solution for general $y(t)$.

Comment: They are two unknown functions $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in only one equation. You expect solve the equation for what ?

Comment: @JJacquelin I try to solve it for $x(t)$

Comment: OK. So, $y(t)$ is a known function and the equation is a Riccati ODE as already mentioned in the comment from projectilmotion. See Eq.(4) in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RiccatiDifferentialEquation.html and follow the method to transform into a linear ODE.

Comment: @JJacquelin I see the idea, thanks !

Comment: @JJacquelin I have a question. Since I have an autonomous differential equation, $t$ does not enter as a direct variable anywhere. Then, is it correct to use this standard method in order to find the solution ?

Comment: It's not autonomous because $t$ a direct variable in the given function $y(t)$.

Comment: @JJacquelin Thanks for your help ! Sorry, I am confused a little bit. In this example $t$ is time and function $y$ is evolving with respect to time. Normally, I have another equation of motion for variable $y(t)$ which is $\frac{dy\left(t\right)}{dt}=by\left(t\right)-z\left(t\right)$. For sure, if we integrate this equation, it will explicitly depend on time $t$ but I have seen a lot of different methods for algebraic riccati equations with "time". Then, my doubt is if I can use the method on the link you have given.

Comment: So, $y(t)$ is not a known function as you let it supposed in your previous comment. There is a second equation $\frac{y(t)}{dt}=by(t)-z(t)$. But what is $z(t)$ ? Again, if you don't give all the terms of the problem it is not possible to expect an appropriate answer.